# php mkdir doesnt work on server

Tags: php

im having a problem with my php script working on local host but failing to create a dir when i upload it to my server:

upload_file.php:

```
   $img_tmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
   $path = mkdir("../path/folder/$id", 0700);
   $filename = "pic.jpg";
   $location ="../path/folder/$id/";
   $move_file = move_uploaded_file($img_tmp,$location.$filename);
```

the folder structure on server is similar.

**FOLDER: path** =>
   **FOLDER: folder** =>
      here the folder $id should be created.

**FOLDER: upload_file** =>
   upload_file.php

can some one please advice to the problem/solution?

Comment: do you have correct permission to create dir??

Comment: `var_dump(is_writeable("../path/folder"))` and what do you get ??

Comment: how can i check if i dont have permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the folder permission, folder permission should be 0777 to upload file.

So try setting the folder permission to 0777 or 0775

```
$path = mkdir("../path/folder/$id", 0777);
```

This should work.

Comment: This is the usual problem occurs when working in unix. one more problem is there like if you try to create more than 2 hierarchy of directory in unix together then it doesn't create directory. For example if you trying to create directory structure like "a/b/c" then it wont create any directory and you might face problem in uploading file.

Answer (score 0):

use absoulute path:

```
$path = mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/folder/$id", 0777);
```